# Where is the largest collection of Romanticism paintings?

Tags: where-on-earth, factoids, artworks

I would like to find out where is the largest collection of paintings from the [Romanticism movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanticism#Visual_arts). By largest I mean not only the more numerous but also with sufficient coverage of different artists, nationalities, and periods. I recently visited the National Gallery in London, and was surprised to find "few" paintings from that period, let alone from [English Romanticists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:English_romantic_painters).

Unfortunately, I haven't been to other major museums (Louvre, Prado, Orsay, Met, etc). There seem to be more English paintings in the [V&A museum](http://www.vam.ac.uk/content/articles/t/the-romantic-tradition-in-british-painting-1800-1950/). Also, there is an [on-going project](https://deutsches-romantik-museum.de/) setting up a German Romanticism museum. Still, the question remains. Where could I find the largest collection of such paintings?

Comment: There might not be a single largest collection. You might try [Tate Britain](https://www.tate.org.uk) with works by Constable, Turner, Blake and others

Comment: @ReddHerring mmm, shouldn't by definition be a largest one, just that it might not be "big enough"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about art with no real connection to travel beyond the trivial fact that the answer is a place and people could travel there.

Comment: @DavidRicherby "where-on-earth" tag reads: **"For questions about location of specific place or location of longest/highest/biggest/the most... place/thing on Earth."** Isn't that precisely what my question is about?

Comment: @fox_mulder This may be a case where the community's ideas about what is on-topic have changed over time.

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/146965/which-museums-have-artworks-of-all-four-ninja-turtles-namesakes is a sillier question with similar topic, thousands of views, several answers and over one hundred upvotes. I wouldn't say that this question is off-topic.

Comment: @Pere That's how arbitrary things seem to be in this site.